# In azure functions using javascript how to call send request to a endpoint

Tags: azure, azure-functions

In Azure function how to call an API using **javascript**. The request is POST with the header.I tried to use **XMLHttpRequest**, but i got exception like this XMLHttpRequest is not defined.

```
var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var authentication = 'Bearer ...'
    var url = "http://example.com";
    var data = '{.........}';

    client.open("POST", url, true);
    client.setRequestHeader('Authorization',authentication); 
    client.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    client.send(data);
```

Any other method is there to achive this,

Comment: Please post your essential code. Thanks!

Comment: I need to call an endpoint which accepts POST method with cookie in header which I'll pass. But I am facing problem in achieving this.

Comment: What is your Azure Functions language?  Also like @David suggested can you post your current code?

Answer (score 9):

You can do it with a built-in `http` module (standard one for node.js):

```js
var http = require('http');

module.exports= function (context) {
  context.log('JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.');

  var options = {
      host: 'example.com',
      port: '80',
      path: '/test',
      method: 'POST'
  };

  // Set up the request
  var req = http.request(options, (res) => {
    var body = "";

    res.on("data", (chunk) => {
      body += chunk;
    });

    res.on("end", () => {
      context.res = body;
      context.done();
    });
  }).on("error", (error) => {
    context.log('error');
    context.res = {
      status: 500,
      body: error
    };
    context.done();
  });
  req.end();
};
```

You can also use any other npm module like `request` if you install it into your Function App.

Comment: That could mean it works :) Have a look at logs and response to understand the reason.

Comment: can i replace host,port and path with url. As I saw in some examples.

Comment: You can make any valid use of `http` or `https` modules that you find in any Node.js example online, it's no different here

Comment: in log i'm getting    2018-06-12T21:08:14.299 [Error] Exception while executing function: Functions.HttpTriggerJS1. mscorlib: One or more errors occurred. Error: Cannot find module 'request'

Comment: Hmm... My code has no reference to `request` module.

Comment: I've done this using the async version and that works well too.

Comment: FYI, the [`request`](https://github.com/request/request) module **has been deprecated.**