# Azure Functions JS: http(s) POST request call inside function not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, https, azure-functions

I am  currently switching from aws lambda to azure functions and try to convert my lambda function (js) to azure function (js). One of the things I need to do in my function is to send a HTTPS Post Request to a URL to get some data. That worked perfectly fine in aws lambda. However, it seems like azure functions is either not supporting this or I am doing something wrong as it never sends the request and just ends the whole function.

This is my code:

```
var https = require('https');
var http = require('http');


module.exports = async function (context, req) {

        var http_options = {
                hostname: 'somehostname',
                port: 443,
                path: 'somepath',
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8',
                        'SOAPAction': '"https://someURL"'
                }
        };

        var body = '';

        context.log('before request');

        var req = await https.request(http_options, function (res) {

            res.setEncoding('utf8');
            body = '';

            context.log('inside request');

            res.on('data', (chunk) => {

                    body = body + chunk;
            });

            context.log('in req 2');

            res.on('end', () => {
                    var options = {
                            compact: false,
                            ignoreComment: false,
                            spaces: 1
                    };

                    var result = JSON.parse(body);
            })
        })


};
```

The function always prints the "before request" part, and the just terminates.

I also tried a simple http call as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50823783/in-azure-functions-using-javascript-how-to-call-send-request-to-a-endpoint) SO question. However, same result, the function just ends.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that `https.request()` is an async method (doesn't return a promise-like type). What if you try removing your await keyword there?

```js
var https = require('https');
var http = require('http');


module.exports = async function (context, req) {

        var http_options = {
                hostname: 'somehostname',
                port: 443,
                path: 'somepath',
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8',
                        'SOAPAction': '"https://someURL"'
                }
        };

        var body = '';

        context.log('before request');

        https.request(http_options, function (res) {

            res.setEncoding('utf8');
            body = '';

            context.log('inside request');

            res.on('data', (chunk) => {

                    body = body + chunk;
            });

            context.log('in req 2');

            res.on('end', () => {
                    var options = {
                            compact: false,
                            ignoreComment: false,
                            spaces: 1
                    };

                    var result = JSON.parse(body);
            });
        });


};
```

Comment: thanks for the input. I tried that out but still the same behaviour. It ends after printing "before request".